# Jenkins: launch same job with different parameters

Tags: jenkins

I have a job to maven build our project, we now have one job per release version. As the number of releases grows, there are too many jobs and very hard to find the one we need.

I wonder if there is a way to launch the same job with different parameters? The problem is one job only has one workspace, so I'm not sure if it's possible?

Thanks.

Comment: 3 seconds of googling: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Comment: The workflow we're using at work is development in release branches, then the changes are merged into the trunk/master and this branch is deployed by Jenkins. This way we need no parameters. The current version is hardcoded and raised regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `This build is Parameterized` option to build the jobs. Using this you can build the same job for different parameters. You will be asked to enter the parameter before building or you can also give a default parameter and you can have multiple parameters.

[image]

It is good the archive the artifacts which you need later.

[image]

You can also have the option `keep build forever`, this will keep the builds permanently Ir-respective of the number of builds to keep.

[image]

To use above option you should enable `Discard old build` option.
[image]

You can also link your repository directly to Jenkins which will trigger the job whenever a new commit is made to `master` or a new `tag` is created.